# iOS Background Service not running the first time

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, background-service

I am having a weird bug where the background service in iOS doesn't start the first time I hit the home button.

My code is simple:

```
//-- app.js
Ti.App.addEventListener('paused', function(event)
{
    Ti.API.info('paused');
    var bgService = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
       url: 'includes/services/ios_bgservice.js'
    });
});
```

---

```
//-- ios_bgservice.js
Ti.API.warn('bg logout process has begun for iOS');
```

My process is:

- compile/launch app in emulator
- simulate the home button (cmd + shift + h)
- console shows ONLY "`paused`". I should see "`paused [new line] bg logout process has begun for iOS`"

If I launch the app again via the dashboard (Do not recompile), then hit the home button, the console shows `paused [new line] bg logout process has begun for iOS`

This had to break somewhere around this year because I know at one point it was working. I have also confirmed the behavior is the same when tested on the device.

**Additional Info**

- Ti Studio, build: 3.1.3.201309132423
- Ti SDK 3.1.3 GA
- iOS7 SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty simple. You cannot register a web service after your application has paused.

You simply write the following lines and your service will automatically be triggered, when your application goes in pause state

```
var service = null;
if(service != null){
service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
       url: 'includes/services/ios_bgservice.js'
    });
}
```

Hope this Helps !!!